# checking permission dynamically

Tags: python, django, permissions, authentication

```
class Task(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("view_task", "Can see available tasks"),
            ("change_task_status", "Can change the status of tasks"),
            ("close_task", "Can remove a task by setting its status as closed"),
        )
user.has_perm('app.view_task')
```

is there any way to check the permission if i have contenttype.codename unknown(not hardcoded) , i.e it come from database dynamically like below

```
permission = Permission.objects.get(id=item.permission_id )
contenttype = ContentType.objects.get(id=permission.content_type_id)               
user.has_perm(appname.contenttype.codename)
```

but it always return false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
user.has_perm(u'%s.%s' % (contenttype.app_label, permission.codename))
```

Also, use

```
contenttype = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Permission)
```